# CSS translate jumps to original position at end of animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

http://jsfiddle.net/mf6ebfL3/

I can't figure out what's going on here. If you hold the mouse over the text, it should slowly pan to the left (which it does), but at the end of the animation, it jumps back to the beginning. And it's not a `mouseleave` event triggering it either.

Note this only works in Chrome for some reason. In Firefox, nothing happens (bonus points if you can answer that one!).

Comment: what should happen after the end of animation ?

Comment: Both your problems happen because transforms are not intended to be applied to `inline` elements (which the `span` is). Add `display: inline-block` to `.ffx-long-text` and the problems both in FF and Chrome will be solved with it. (I am wondering how I will get the bonus points :D)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/9ven45jj/
have fun!

Comment: @Harry Nice, please post that as an answer!

Comment: @ffxsam: Its the same as the answer in the thread that I had linked (the duplicate notice). So, didn't add another answer as it would look like rep-hunting.

Comment: @Harry But those bonus points I promised! ;) Ok, no worries. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I upvoted your answer on the other question you linked to

Comment: @ffxsam: That's ok pal. I was just kidding. I am happy that it helped you (and thanks for the upvote) :)